# Finding the basis of the kernel for a specific linear map f?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $f$ be the linear map:

$$ f := P^3 → \mathbb{R}^2, \ \ f(X) = \begin{pmatrix} f(1) \\ f'(0) \end{pmatrix}$$

where $P^3$ is the vector space of polynomials of degree $\leq 3$, and $f'$ is the first derivative of $f$.

Standard bases are given for $P^3$, $\{1, X, X^2, X^3\}$, and for $\mathbb{R}^2 $, $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$.

I want to find a basis for the kernel of $f$.

Here is what my attempt consisted of:

First, I used the dimension formula:

$\dim(\ker(f)) + \dim(\text{image}(f)) = \dim(\text{domain}(f))$

Since the domain $P^3$ has dimension $4$, and the image is in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of dimension $2$, the kernel must have dimension $2$.

So the kernel basis must contain two linearly independent elements.

And then, since I look for kernel of $f$ , I know every $f$ must fulfill the property $f(1)=0$ and $f'(0) = 0 $

After that, I tried to find a suitable linear combination of the $P^3$-space.

Here i am stuck, then checked the internet for similiar.

After brooding about it some time i thought about the basis and that it should contain atleast $X^2-X^3$, but that seems like a poor attempt to me. I am not sure, if that actually is minimal.

So, would someone share their ideas for a basis with me?

Any feedback is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your sentence *…and the image is in $\mathbb R^2$ of dimension 2, the kernel must have dimension 2* contains an incorrect conclusion. The image is indeed included in $\mathbb R^2$, you have to prove that **it is equal to $\mathbb R^2$**. But in fact it is easier to prove directly that the kernel has a dimension equal to 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the kernel directly. Let $p\in \ker f$. As $p(1)=0$, $x-1$ divides $p$ and you can write $p(x)=(x-1)q(x)$, where the degree of $q$ is at most $2$. $p^\prime(x)=q(x)+(x-1)q^\prime(x)$ and $p^\prime(0)=q(0)-q^\prime(0)=0$. Therefore $$q(x)= a + ax + bx^2,$$ where $a,b \in \mathbb R$. And a basis of $\ker f$ is $\{(x-1)(x+1), (x-1)x^2\}$.